# How to display a notification box then remove it with Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, popup, notifications

I'd like to use the native notification box with andriod, or any device you're using to popup whilst the app is trying to access the internet. Or at least when it needs to access it if its a stopper for the user.

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Please wait...',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Signing In!',            // title
);
```

Whilst this will open the alert, it will open with an OK button, so my question.

If I could somehow remove the ok button I still wouldn't have a way to hide away the notification.

How can you make a popup appear and then remove it when ready?

**Edit**

To make this very clear this is the kind of dialog I would like to use:
[image]

When this is open the user can do nothing until this has been taken away from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to Show Notification popup without 'ok' Button. it will be hide after 2 seconds.

```
function showPopup(text){
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
        text: text,
        textVisible: true,
        textonly: true,
        theme: 'e',
    });
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, 2000);
}
```

You can call that function By:

```
showPopup('Please wait..');
```

Comment: its a jquery function from jquery mobile? wheres the $ coming from :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find a way to hide the buttons, there is still an other way to close the notation: just tap anywhere else on the screen. So there will be no native-solution.

You may should create a div and set its position absolute.